# How can I replace all numbers of an array with all numbers of an other array except of the zeros (Python, numpy)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays like these:

```
a = [[1,2,-3],[4,5,-6],[7,8,9]]
b = [[2,-5,0],[0,4,8],[-2,1,0]]
```

Every number of "a" should be replaced with the one from "b", except of those, where the number of "b" is 0:

```
result = [[2,-5,-3],[4,4,8],[-2,1,9]]
```

My current solution takes way too long:

```
for row in range(len(b)):
    for column in range(len(b[row])):
        if b[row][column] != 0 or b[row][column] != -0:
            a[row][column] = b[row][column]
```

Btw. is the "b[row][column] != -0" necessary? Since there are sometimes "0"s and sometimes "-0"s in b.

Is there a fast way? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `np.where()`

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
a = np.where(b == 0, a, b)
```

If you want to get fancy and save memory, use `np.place()`

```
np.place(a, b != 0, b[b != 0])
```

EDIT: Since `0 == -0` evaluates `True`, you don't need any other checks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
a[np.where(b !=0)] = b[np.where(b !=0)]
```